# React Native App always opening on the login screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, navigation, react-navigation

I have a problem with my react native app. It's always opening on the login screen, but I want to open the main screen when the user is already logged. I'm using the AsyncStorage to verify if the token is null or not. If the token is null, I set the state screen to 'Login', if not I set the state screen to 'Main'. But I think the navigator is returned before the state changes. But I don't know how to make it in the right way. Please help me!

my navigator  (I'm using react-navigation v5)

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import Login from '../screens/Login'
import Register from '../screens/Register'
import Main from '../screens/Main'
import TransactionRegistration from '../screens/TransactionRegistration'

import { renewLogin } from '../store/actions/user'
import '../config/ReactotronConfig'

const StackMain = createStackNavigator()

class Navigator extends PureComponent {
    state = {
        screen: 'Login',
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.isLogged()
            .then(res => this.setState({ screen: res}))
            .catch(err => alert('An error occurred'))
    }

    isLogged = async() => {
        let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_token')
        let id = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@user_id')

        const user = {
            id: id,
            token: token
        }

        if (token !== null) {
            await this.props.onRenewLogin(user)
            return 'Main'
        }
        else {
            return 'Login'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <StackMain.Navigator initialRouteName={this.state.screen}>
                    <StackMain.Screen
                        component={Login}
                        name='Login'
                        options={{headerShown: false}} />
                    <StackMain.Screen
                        component={Register}
                        name='Register'
                        options={{headerShown: false}} />
                    <StackMain.Screen
                        component={Main}
                        name='Main'
                        options={{headerShown: false}} />
                    <StackMain.Screen
                        component={TransactionRegistration}
                        name='TransactionRegistration'
                        options={{headerShown: false}} />
                </StackMain.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        )
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onRenewLogin: user => dispatch(renewLogin(user)),
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Navigator)
```

my login screen (See that I navigate to Main when the login is successful)

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { 
    login,
} from '../../store/actions/user'
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Animated,
    StatusBar,
} from 'react-native'

import { validateForm } from '../../common/utils/validators'
import AuthContainer from '../../components/Auth/AuthContainer'
import AuthTitle from '../../components/Auth/AuthTitle'
import AuthButton from '../../components/Auth/AuthButton'
import AuthInput from '../../components/Auth/AuthInput'
import AuthHeader from '../../components/Auth/AuthHeader'
import SpeechBubble from '../../components/Auth/SpeechBubble'

import styles from '../../assets/css/styles'
import { colors } from '../../assets/css/colors'

class Login extends PureComponent {
    state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        text: 'Olá! Cadastrou sua conta usando e-mail e senha? Insira-os aqui:',
        messageError: '',
        shakeAnimation: new Animated.Value(0),
        formError: false,
    }

    componentDidUpdate = (prevProps, prevState) => {
        if(prevProps.isLoading && !this.props.isLoading && this.props.token){
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Main')
        }
        if(prevProps.loginError != this.props.loginError && this.props.loginError != ''){
            this.setState({ text: this.props.loginError, formError: true})
        }
        if(prevState.text != this.state.text){
            this.handleAnimation()
        }
    }

    login = async() => {
        this.setState({messageError: validateForm('login', this.state)})
        if (this.state.messageError == '') {
            await this.props.onLogin({ ...this.state })
            if (this.props.loginError != '') {
                this.setState({ text: this.props.loginError, formError: true})
                this.handleAnimation()
            }
        }
        else {
            this.setState({text: this.state.messageError, formError: true})
            this.handleAnimation()
        }
    }

    navigateToRegister = () => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')
    }

    handleAnimation = () => {
        Animated.sequence([
            Animated.timing(this.state.shakeAnimation, { toValue: 10, duration: 80, useNativeDriver: true }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.shakeAnimation, { toValue: -10, duration: 80, useNativeDriver: true }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.shakeAnimation, { toValue: 10, duration: 80, useNativeDriver: true }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.shakeAnimation, { toValue: 0, duration: 80, useNativeDriver: true })
          ]).start() 
    }

    render(){
        
        return (

            <AuthContainer>
                <StatusBar backgroundColor={colors.screenBg} barStyle='dark-content' />
                <AuthHeader />

                <SpeechBubble>
                    <Animated.View
                        style={{ transform: [{translateX: this.state.shakeAnimation}] }}>
                    <AuthTitle 
                        text={this.state.text} 
                        styleTitle={!this.state.formError ? [styles.loginFont, styles.bodyText] :
                            [styles.loginFont, styles.bodyText, styles.bodyTextError]}/>
                    </Animated.View>
                    <AuthInput
                        placeholder='Seu e-mail'
                        keyboardType='email-address'
                        autoFocus={true}
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        autoCapitalize='none'
                        returnKeyType='next'
                        value={this.state.email}
                        onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                        blurOnSubmit={false} />

                    <AuthInput 
                        placeholder='Sua senha'
                        returnKeyType='go'
                        value={this.state.password}
                        password={true}
                        onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })} />

                    <AuthButton title='Entrar' onPress={() => this.login()}/>

                    <View style={styles.bodyBottom}>
                        <Text style={[styles.loginFont, styles.bodyLink]}>Esqueci minha senha</Text>

                        <Text style={[styles.loginFont, styles.bodyLink]} onPress={this.navigateToRegister}>
                            Ainda não cadastrei uma conta
                        </Text>
                    </View>
                </SpeechBubble>
            </AuthContainer>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ user }) => {
    return {
        isLoading: user.isLoading,
        token: user.token,
        loginError: user.loginError,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onLogin: user => dispatch(login(user)),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)
```

Comment: Did you check if you are getting token or not?

Comment: @SanyamJain, yes I did

Answer (score 0):

You are right at the time of the first render the initialRouteName is Login and it doesn't matter if you change it with state it already rendered the login, the easier way to solve is to actually initialize the app in login and then use the navigation prop method navigate to send the user to expected screen.

So in your componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount = () => {
        this.isLogged()
            .then(res => { 
                this.props.navigation.navigate(res);
            })
            .catch(err => alert('An error occurred'))
    }
```

Comment: It always return me the alert with the error, I think I don't have access to the navigate method there. I tried to pass 'Main' instead of res, and still not working

Comment: actually the navigation is not inside the props of this class, because its not a screen.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a class component instead of a hook? i ask because in this case you can migrate this component to a hook and use the hook useNavigation available in react navigation v5, the other thing is that you can put this validation/functionality in your login screen component did mount where you have the nav prop